# python difflib.context_diff doesnt show all the elements

Tags: python, comparator, txt, difflib

I'm trying to compare two .txt files in order to observe the changes have been done before. these files contains of list informations, you can see them below. If last 4 elements are exactly same, then the function doesn't print them on the screen but I'd like to see all the information to check if its changed, added or deleted.

Here's my code

```
import difflib

def compare_text_files(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        text1 = f1.readlines()
        text2 = f2.readlines()

    differ = difflib.Differ()
    diff = list(differ.compare(text1, text2))
    diff = list(difflib.context_diff(text1, text2))

    return diff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file1 = 'test1.txt'
    file2 = 'test2.txt' 
    differences = compare_text_files(file1, file2)
    for line in differences:
        print(line)`
```

and the test files:
test1.txt
A1: blu
B1: yellow
C3: red
D6: green
E5: white
F9: grey
H8: black
A2: turuncu

tes2.txt
A1: blue
B1: yellow
C3: red
D6: green
E5: white
F9: grey
H8: black
A2: turuncu

Comment: Can you show your exact expected output ?